# Constrained least squares estimation

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

I need to fit a regression model using least squares in R with the constraint that the parameters are positive. they DON'T need to sum to one. because some times parameter sum exceeds one.

Can someone help me with the code pease

Comment: If the parameters need to be positive, try fitting the model $Y=e^{\beta_0}+\sum_{i=1}^{p}e^{\beta_i}X_i+\varepsilon$ instead of $Y=\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_iX_i+\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Max, why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: There is a blog showing how to do this using the nnls library at http://www.jameskeirstead.ca/blog/positive-coefficient-regression-in-r/ .  Someone with the time to check and paraphrase that could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

1) You could fit it by putting box-type constraints to an optimizer that can deal with them - see ?optim and ?nlminb, for example.

2) You could use code like this: http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~meyer/constrparam.R

3) You could use a package designed to have positivity-constrained models, such as the package `penalized`

4) you can use nonlinear LS in various ways to ensure non-negative or strictly positive regressions.

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this task is to alter your model slightly. Rather than fitting the typical model of $$Y=\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\beta_iX_i+\varepsilon$$ instead fit the model $$Y=e^{\beta_0}+\sum_{i=1}^{p}e^{\beta_i}X_i+\varepsilon$$ This can still be fit by least squares fairly easily in R and it has the effect of forcing the coefficients to be non-negative.

**Edit**

Here's some code to accomplish the model fitting. Using `nls` gives both parameter estimates and variances.

```
# generate data

set.seed(1)
x <- cbind(1, matrix(rnorm(900, 1:9), nrow=100))
beta <- runif(10, 0, 1)
y <- x %*% beta + rnorm(100)

# try using nls function

ests <- nls(y ~ exp(b0) + exp(b1)*x[,2] + exp(b2)*x[,3] + exp(b3)*x[,4] +
                          exp(b4)*x[,5] + exp(b5)*x[,6] + exp(b6)*x[,7] + 
                          exp(b7)*x[,8] + exp(b8)*x[,9] + exp(b9)*x[,10],
            start = list(b0 = runif(1), b1 = runif(1), b2 = runif(1), b3 = runif(1),
                         b4 = runif(1), b5 = runif(1), b6 = runif(1), b7 = runif(1),
                         b8 = runif(1), b9 = runif(1)))

summary(ests)

exp(coef(ests))
```

Comment: can you give me an example code please?

Comment: @dav I've added code. I hope that helps.

Comment: This is clever, but I worry that it will fail in precisely those circumstances where it is most needed: if one of the coefficients is negative for OLS, then most likely the optimal solution with this approach occurs where its logarithm approaches $-\infty$.  That may cause instability in `nls`.  It would therefore be good to see this method solve a realistic example accurately.

Comment: The code you posted fails for me (`R` 2.15.2) at the `nls` call with a "step factor <> reduced below 'minFactor' of <>" message. Regardless, because you generate only positive betas to begin with, this is scarcely a difficult test of the procedure! The challenge is to get it to work reliably when one or more of the components of `beta` are *negative*.

Comment: @whuber I apologize for not responding earlier. I actually share your concerns. This method will absolutely fail if any of the coefficients are negative. In fact, my guess is this method will fail if any coefficients are small and positive. And now that I'm thinking more deeply about the situation, this method may perform worse than OLS even when all coefficients are positive depending on their magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quadratic programming problem:
Let $\mathbf I\in\mathbb R^{n\times 9}$, be your design matrix ($n$ is the number of measurements, so each row contains one measurement with the investments $I_1,\ldots, I_9$), and $\boldsymbol \beta\in\mathbb R^9$ your linear coefficients, which you want to be nonnegative (at least some of them). Then you want to minimize the cost function $c(\mathbf I, \boldsymbol \beta)$, which is the sum of the quadratic residuals,  under the nonnegativity constraint on $\boldsymbol\beta$:
$$
\begin{align}
c(\mathbf X, \boldsymbol\beta) &:= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{k=1}^9 I_{ik}\beta_k - Y_i\right)^2\\
\beta_i &\ge 0,\quad i=1,\ldots,9.
\end{align}
$$
Since $c$ is a quadratic function of $\boldsymbol \beta$ and you have inequality constraints on $\boldsymbol \beta$, this is a [quadratic programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), and there is [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_(programming)_languages) for solving it.

Comment: hi frank, nice to meet you again. Are there any way to find a constraints which will let the coefficients be positive ?

Comment: @nobodyishere :) If you obtain a minimum with some $\beta_i = 0$, this just means that you should not do the investment $I_i$. Why do you need $\beta_i$ to be strictly greater than zero?

Comment: Hi frank, the problems is that is not easy to tell the customer that your some of investments are jerk, they are not making any extra sales. Therefore, I cannot try `penalize()` package which will give me some `0 coefficients` while these coefficients are used to be negative. So, I have to make all coefficients be positive. All `I` must be included in the model and with positive coefficients.

Comment: @nobodyishere Well then I would recommend using as constraints $\beta_i \ge b$ with $b$ the smallest positive value that you think will be tolerated.

Comment: Could you give me a brief `code  example` or something related to how to find the `smallest b`?

Answer (score 1):

[The `pcls()` function in the `mgcv` package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/pcls.html) does partially constrained least squares. You can include equality and/or inequality constraints on some or all of the parameter estimates, and in fact on linear combinations of them. (It also allows for quadratic penalties, which are probably not relevant in your case.)

An alternative (which I found by [searching for "constrained least squares in R"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=constrained+least+squares+in+r)) would be [`cls()` in the `cols` package](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/cols/html/cls.html) (which I haven't used yet, but take a look).