# Can I specify the signs on coefficients of variables in Regression models?

Tags: regression, inference, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have a Regression model where the coefficients of each variable need specific signs.

For Example, say I have a standard OLS model:  Y = β1X1 + β2X2 + … +  β7X7. I want coefficients β2 and β5 to be negative and the remaining coefficients to be positive.

Using the glmnet package in R, I have tried to constrain for the signs by applying bounds (lower and upper) for the maximum and minimum values each coefficient can take (zero to infinity to be positive and vice versa for negative).

Even after imposing such restrictions, for certain variables the coefficient values are coming out to be exactly zero.

What is the reason behind this? and how can one get around this problem to maintain specific signs?

Additionally, I would appreciate suggestions for packages (preferably in R or Python) or other software if this problem has already been solved.

Comment: Would it be more useful to you to have a parameter estimate of 0.00001 rather than 0? If so, you can of course use that as a bound, rather than 0, and -0.00001 if you really want a negative coefficient. [This thread may be helpful.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51194/1352)

Comment: Consider that if the least square solution requires the number to be negative and you bound it to be positive, the "most" positive it can be is zero.

Comment: One solution could be to reparametrize your model and optimize the reparametrized log-likelihood yourself.

Comment: Are you open to Bayesian solutions to your problem? Then you could encode your requirement via priors.

Comment: @Kuku No, I am looking for frequentist solutions solve this.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you for your response. I am trying to solve this problem through least squares method specifically. If I have relatively high negative coefficients in the model, then are there any methods to bring them to the positive scale.

Comment: Your data and your model are telling you there is a negative relationship. Why do you think a positive coefficient makes more sense than a zero? If your model gives you a large negative coefficient where you expected a positive one, it may be that your model is off. One possible reason is collinearity between predictors.

Comment: @utobi Can you specify what exactly you mean when you say reparametrize the model?

Comment: Why do you want these coefficients to be positive or negative? Are you maybe planning to do one-sided test?